# How to activate onbeforeunload after window.location reloads the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I use `onbeforeunload` in my project. However there is a section where user can click on the link and download report(s). Before `window.location` is being triggered I set `window.onbeforeunload = null` that way user won't be getting alert/confirm box with the question to leave or stay. There is a problem once they click on report and download the file if they try to close the browser `onbeforeunload` is not triggered again. How I can trigger `onbeforeunload` after report is downloaded? Here is example of my function:

```
function getReport(){
    var fileName = $(this).prop('id'),
    param = 'rptFile=' + fileName;  

    try{
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
        window.location = '/'+pathname+'/APPS/entry.cfm?idx=5&' + param;
    }catch(err){
        alert("An error occurred retrieving the file.");
    }
};
```

My main page that I'm reloading `entry.cfm` has `document.ready` function where I have onbeforeunload function. I expected once report is downloaded with `window.location` then onbeforeunload will br triggered again. So I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or this is not possible with JS. Here is `entry.cfm` example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
    }
});
```

If anyone knows how to trigger onbeforeunload again please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: put some flag in cookie or in localstorage to know when user download reports.. if they did then attach onbeforeload again

Comment: @KresimirPendic That's what I was wondering how to attach onbeforeunload again? I was hoping if I have that in document.ready that will do the trick.

Comment: [This may help you](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp), also, why instead of reloading your window, open a new one to download the report or use an iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, do not `null` `window.onbeforeunload` just replace your `window.location` with `window.open` to open report in new tab.

```js
function getReport() {
  try {
    window.open('https://via.placeholder.com/350x150/ee5533', '_blank');
  } catch (err) {
    alert("An error occurred retrieving the file.");
  }
};


window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
}

$('.dwl').on('click', getReport );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="dwl">Try to download in new tab</a>
```

Comment: Kresimire this works! Thank's for your help. I hope that users won't get confused because once they click on the link new window jumps for a sec before report gets downloaded.